# Can anyone recommend any books with useful notes on Groups and Symmetries? (group theory)

Tags: group-theory, soft-question, education, book-recommendation, symmetric-groups

I'm currently at university and I want to expand my reading knowledge on my upcoming modules. Thanks.

Comment: The question is to broad. I like Abstract Algebra by Dummit and Foote. It covers everything you need to know and more. It is not special about groups and symmetries though, but I do not know what you expect. What is your background on mathematics so far?

Comment: If you're prepping, Pinter is a good book. It has a good collection of exercises, and I think the exposition is quite good. It's also cheap, if you want a physical copy.

Comment: See [physics stackexchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/232233/symmetry-and-group-theory-book).

Comment: I have studied Linear algebra which briefly mentioned groups and symmetries. I have looked through the Introduction to Algebra by Peter J. Cameron. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A good book for beginning Group theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1652937/a-good-book-for-beginning-group-theory). If not, there are copious numbers of other questions on group theory recommendations in both this link and others. You just need to search. Before asking, ideally.